# Get values from XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby

I want parse the values from *XML* using *Nokogiri*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment_response>
    <transaction_type>intersolve</transaction_type>
    <status>declined</status>
    <unique_id>a092ae8bac0ebc8c63dae3e0bd46331c</unique_id>
    <transaction_id>fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5</transaction_id>
    <code>540</code>
    <technical_message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</technical_message>
    <message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</message>
    <mode>test</mode>
    <timestamp>2017-11-23T12:36:25Z</timestamp>
    <descriptor>test</descriptor>
    <amount>1000</amount>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <sent_to_acquirer>false</sent_to_acquirer>
</payment_response>

payment_response = Nori.new(:parser => :nokogiri, :advanced_typecasting => false).parse(@response)
```

How I can get the values from `payment_response`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using xpath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

XML = <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment_response>
    <transaction_type>intersolve</transaction_type>
    <status>declined</status>
    <unique_id>a092ae8bac0ebc8c63dae3e0bd46331c</unique_id>
    <transaction_id>fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5</transaction_id>
    <code>540</code>
    <technical_message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</technical_message>
    <message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</message>
    <mode>test</mode>
    <timestamp>2017-11-23T12:36:25Z</timestamp>
    <descriptor>test</descriptor>
    <amount>1000</amount>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <sent_to_acquirer>false</sent_to_acquirer>
</payment_response>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML XML
doc.xpath('//payment_response/*').each { |element| puts element }
# <transaction_id>fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5</transaction_id>
# <code>540</code>
# <technical_message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.
```

Using Nori:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML XML
parser = Nori.new parser: :nokogiri
p doc.xpath('//payment_response/*').map { |tag| parser.parse tag.to_s }
# [
#   {"transaction_type"=>"intersolve"}, 
#   {"status"=>"declined"}, 
#   {"unique_id"=>"a092ae8bac0ebc8c63dae3e0bd46331c"}, 
#   {"transaction_id"=>"fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5"}, 
#   ...
# ]
```

Comment: Is there other solution?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Using 'nori':

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'nori'

@response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment_response>
    <transaction_type>intersolve</transaction_type>
    <status>declined</status>
    <unique_id>a092ae8bac0ebc8c63dae3e0bd46331c</unique_id>
    <transaction_id>fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5</transaction_id>
    <code>540</code>
    <technical_message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</technical_message>
    <message>Amount exceeds credit card limit.</message>
    <mode>test</mode>
    <timestamp>2017-11-23T12:36:25Z</timestamp>
    <descriptor>test</descriptor>
    <amount>1000</amount>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <sent_to_acquirer>false</sent_to_acquirer>
</payment_response>'

full_response = Nori.new(:parser => :nokogiri, :advanced_typecasting 
=> false).parse(@response)
```

here you get Hash with the key `payment_response`. What you are looking is inside it's value

```
full_response.map {|k1,v1|
    # puts "%s : %s /n" % [k1,v1]
    if v1.instance_of? Hash
        v1.map {|k2, v2|
            puts "%s : %s" % [k2,v2] # or [k2,v1[k2]]
        }
    end
}
```

My output is:

```
transaction_type : intersolve
status : declined
unique_id : a092ae8bac0ebc8c63dae3e0bd46331c
transaction_id : fa3fw6dwdeadesr7rd8e1c080600d6f5
code : 540
technical_message : Amount exceeds credit card limit.
message : Amount exceeds credit card limit.
mode : test
timestamp : 2017-11-23T12:36:25Z
descriptor : test
amount : 1000
currency : EUR
sent_to_acquirer : false
```

Comment: I get `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: @Peter, in which line?